# Linearmodels FamaMacBeth 'list' argument must have no negative elements

Tags: python, numpy, regression, linearmodels

I'm trying to run some Fama MacBeth regressions using the FamaMacBeth functionality from linearmodels (version 4.8) and I'm running into the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-7-f393d4c071f0> in do_panel(list_dfs, y_var, control_vars, 
method)
      37         print(fmb_df[y_var].head())
      38         print(fmb_df[new_x_vars].head())
 ---> 39         model = FamaMacBeth(fmb_df[y_var], sm.add_constant(fmb_df[new_x_vars])).fit()
      40     return model
      41 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\linearmodels\panel\model.py in fit(self, cov_type, debiased, **cov_config)
     1940         cov = cov_est(wy, wx, params, all_params, debiased=debiased, **cov_config)
     1941         df_resid = wy.shape[0] - params.shape[0]
  -> 1942         res = self._postestimation(params, cov, debiased, df_resid, weps, wy, wx, root_w)
     1943         index = self.dependent.index
     1944         res.update(dict(df_resid=df_resid, df_model=x.shape[1], nobs=y.shape[0],

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\linearmodels\panel\model.py in _postestimation(self, params, cov, debiased, df_resid, weps, y, x, root_w)
     441         f_pooled = InapplicableTestStatistic(reason='Model has no effects',
     442                                              name='Pooled F-stat')
 --> 443         entity_info, time_info, other_info = self._info()
     444         nobs = weps.shape[0]
     445         sigma2 = float(weps.T @ weps / nobs)

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\linearmodels\panel\model.py in _info(self)
     223 
     224         entity_info = stats(self.dependent.entity_ids.squeeze(),
 --> 225                             'Observations per entity')
     226         time_info = stats(self.dependent.time_ids.squeeze(),
     227                           'Observations per time period')

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\linearmodels\panel\model.py in stats(ids, name)
     217 
     218         def stats(ids, name):
 --> 219             bc = np.bincount(ids)
     220             index = ['mean', 'median', 'max', 'min', 'total']
     221             out = [bc.mean(), np.median(bc), bc.max(), bc.min(), bc.shape[0]]

ValueError: 'list' argument must have no negative elements
```

I tried Googling around and the only other hit I get is from the numpy source:
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c

I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong. Surely the values in my pandas DataFrame are allowed to be negative right? Help is much appreciated, many thanks in advance!

EDIT: Updated with detailed error Traceback.

Comment: Can you provide additional context around where in your code the error is occurring?  A code sample showing where the error occurs would be great!

Comment: I edited the original post with a more detailed error traceback. I'm pretty sure the error occurs in FamaMacBeth because when I take a more simplified dataframe with just part of my data and just run: FamaMacBeth(y_var, sm.add_constant(fmb_df[x_vars])).fit(), I get the same error. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you!  What's happening is `np.bincount()` does not accept negative values, which is why you're getting the error.  The `linearmodels` package should really have logic to make sure this fails gracefully with a more informative error message.

Comment: Thanks! So do you have any idea what gets passed to np.bincount() so I can avoid it?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the input data you're using so we could recreate the error?  It looks like some kind of derivation from the index of the DataFrame is being passed to `np.bincount()`, but the structure of your data can impact what that index looks like.

Comment: Ah never mind, I figured it out. One of my indices was nan and onceI dropped it, it worked fine. Thanks for your help!